# getting the count value from the querystring

Tags: java, sql

Suppose I have a Querystring defined as follows:

```
String MyTableCount =  "SELECT"
                         + "COUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT "
                         + " FROM "
                          // and so on
```

How do I access the `"TOTALCOUNT"` value  as I want to compare it's value to another value?

I was thinking something like the following:

```
if((MyTableCount.TOTALCOUNT) > 100 )
{

}

else
{

}
```

But this generates an error, as TOTALCOUNT variable needs to be defined.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but are you actually running your database query against the Database using a connection, statement, and ResetSet?  If so you can pull the data from the ResultSet and store it to access it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are right, I shall look at that option.

Comment: `MyTableCount.TOTALCOUNT` does not make sense. `MyTableCount` is your query string, which you should pass to one of the query execution methods.

Answer (score 3):

You need to print out the query string.  According to what you have, it starts as:

```
SELECTCOUNT(*) AS TOTALCOUNT
```

This is not a recognized SQL command.  You need a space after the `SELECT`.

Comment: Agreed.  Staying away from unnecessarily concatenating your queries would avoid issues like this.

Comment: @TinyHaitian Did you mean to stay that I should write the full query in one line?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Your answer sounds more towards correcting the SQL String rather than what I actually asked. May I know why? Anyways, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @John . . . If the SQL string is not formatted correctly, it will not run.  If it doesn't run,  you cannot get results from it.

Comment: @John, that what I would do.